# Jquery Fancybox draggable issue with Scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using a fancybox with plugin `jquery.easydrag.js`. The reason for this is to be able to drag the fancybox around.

It seems to be working fine, but the problem comes when the fancybox has scrollbars. I.e. for example when clicking on submit and not entering any fields the valdidation on screen causes scrollbars. Which is fine normally but the scrollbars causes all sorts of issues with the draggable feature so that when I am trying to click the scrollbar up and down, it actually moves the entire windows. So it seems to be confused as to what content can be moved and what to do with a scrollbar.

```
        claimLink.fancybox({
        'width': 500,
        'height': 590,
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'onCleanup': function (e) {

            var modelClaimFormId = $j(e).attr("href").replace("body", "");
            var modalClaimForm = $j(modelClaimFormId);

            if (!($j(modalClaimForm).valid())) {
                $j(claimForm).remove();
                $j(e).parents("tr").remove();
            }

        }
    });

    $j("#fancybox-wrap").easydrag(true);
```

EDIT :

I managed to add something for input and textareas to ignore the scrolling see below...just wondering what I can do for scrollbars.

```
                $j("#fancybox-wrap").easydrag(true);

            $j("#fancybox-wrap input,textarea").click(function(){
                $j("#fancybox-wrap").dragOff();
            });
            $j("#fancybox-wrap input,textarea").mouseover(function () {
                $j("#fancybox-wrap").dragOff();
            });
            $j("#fancybox-wrap input,textarea").blur(function () {
                $j("#fancybox-wrap").dragOn();
            });
            $j("#fancybox-wrap input,textarea").mouseout(function () {
                $j("#fancybox-wrap").dragOn();
            });
```

[This](http://fromvega.com/code/easydrag/jquery.easydrag.handler.beta2.js) is the link to JS for easydrag plugin

Comment: Hi Steve, it would be really helpful if you also showed your HTML so we get a feel for what you're doing on the content side of things. Thank you.

Comment: yo can basically see the scrollbar issue here http://jquery.diaz-cornen.com/fancybox/index_dragfancybox.html..clicking on the second link click here to see the movie in a draggable fancybox - AJAX

Comment: Oh yeh, I see now. The first was very nice and smooth. The second... not so much... Have you tried editing the CSS for the fancybox container and using overflow:none to eliminate the scrollbars, assuming you don't need them? I replaced overflow auto on #fancy_ajax and that seemed to make it behave a little better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I posted the [first example](http://jquery.diaz-cornen.com/fancybox/index_dragfancybox.html) about how to make fancybox draggable back in 2009 for v1.2.1. Then I posted some notes to make it work with v1.3.1 [as seen here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/9988b208404066b9/) but when fancybox v1.3.4 was introduced, the `easyDrag` plugin was not working as smooth as with the previous versions and started behaving buggy. I didn't have the time to find a workaround ... so I just drop it.

The solution was simple though: the `easyDrag` plugin provides a way to set a "**handler**" [as explained here](http://fromvega.com/wordpress/2007/07/14/easydrag-jquery-plugin/) so instead of holding and dragging the whole `#fancybox-wrap` container, which blocks access to the scroll bars if any,  you just drag the lightbox from a specific defined element. Such **handler** can be appended to `#fancybox-wrap` selector and set it within the EasyDrag plugin using the `onComplete` callback API option like:

```
'onComplete': function(){
  // append the handler on the top-left corner of fancybox
   $("#fancybox-wrap").append("<button id='handler'>Drag me</button>");
  // set the handler using the handler's element ID
   $("#fancybox-wrap").setHandler('handler');
}
```

Notice that you can use any element as handler, in my example I used a html button but you may use an image if preferred. The important thing is to assign the minimum important `css` properties to the handler so it can be appended to the `#fancybox-wrap` container without issue like:

```
width: 80px; /* or whatever needed */
height: 24px;
position: absolute; /* important to position the handler into the fancybox wrap */
top: 0; /* top-left corner of the box but can be anywhere */
left: 0;
display: block;
z-index: 1120; /* important to be over the box */
```

other properties can be cosmetic.

See it [working here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxDraggableScrollBars_25may12BIS.html)!!!

Once you complete and submit the form, the response will be a new fancybox with scroll bars that you can use independently from the easyDrag handler.

Please feel free to analyze the code and customize it to your own needs (and don't forget to grant me the bounty  ;)

**UPDATE**: Notice that since we are appending the handler to the `#fancybox-wrap` container every time we fire fancybox, then we need to remove it once we close fancybox using the `onClosed` callback, otherwise we will duplicate the handler if we open fancybox again with unexpected results:

```
'onClosed' : function() {
  $("#fancybox-wrap #handler").remove();
}
```

I updated [my DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxDraggableScrollBars_25may12BIS.html) too.

**LAST NOTE**: This solution is for fancybox *v1.3.4*.

I haven't tested it with *v2.x* but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Just make sure that you bind `EasyDrag` and append the handler to the `.fancybox-wrap` selector instead

```
$(".fancybox-wrap").easydrag();
```

You may use the `afterShow` callback to append the handler to it and `afterClose` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks man I will try this today, and if all good will ofc reward bounty !

Comment: Thanks man got it working thanks to your solution, the SetHandler did the trick !

Comment: Nice work! The "handler" idea has actually come in handy in some other areas where there is buggy behavior. I'm kinda kicking myself for not thinking of that ;)  +1

Answer (score 2):

Using the above solution to add a handler for the #fancybox-wrap selector along with the  EasyDrag plugin using the onComplete callback API, I found this works nicely with the fancybox 1.3.4 title element to create a dragable fancybox with scroll functionality.  Using the title, there is no need to remove it after close.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js")"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js")"></script> 
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.easydrag.handler.beta2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script>    
     //Fancybox
     $(document).ready(function () {            
         $("#iframeVideoPop").fancybox({
             'width': 890,
             'height': 595,
             'type': 'iframe',
             'autoScale': 'false',
             'hideOnContentClick': false,
             'onComplete': function() {
                  //Style the title where and how you want it
                  $("#fancybox-title").css({'top':'-20px', 'bottom':'auto'});
                  //Set the fancybox-title as the handler
                  $("#fancybox-wrap").setHandler('fancybox-title');
               }
         });

        $("#fancybox-wrap").easydrag();

     }); //ready
 <script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to eliminate the scrollbar problem caused by combining Easydrag with Fancybox, you'll need to eliminate the scrollbars. By default, the Fancybox CSS stylesheet applies the `overflow:auto` rule to the element -- generated by Fancybox -- that wraps around the content displayed inside the Fancybox.

To override it, include your own CSS rule that supersedes the one that Fancybox applies to the wrapper. Place this style block in the `<head>` section of your web page:

```
<style>

    /* id of the element generated and used by Fancybox as a wrapper around
       the generated content. */
    #fancy_ajax {
        /* Use the important identifier to ensure the overflow:auto is suppressed */
        overflow:none !important;

    }
</style>
```

This will eliminate the scrollbars and allow the easy drag plugin to work smoothly.

Comment: as far as I understood, he will need the scrollbars to see the content generated after the validation function. eliminating the scrollbars may solve one issue but may create another one.

Comment: @JFK - Yes, I didn't catch that until about 5 or 6 hours later. I plan to look into this more to see if there's a way to make it work with scrollbars. If not, I'm sure someone will find this useful, if not StevieB. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: Thanks for your solution as well jmort

Answer (score 0):

After testing these solutions I ran into the problem with dragging an iframe.  To resolve, I switched to the [jQuery 1.9.1 UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) plugin for dragging and created a transparent image while dragging.  Remove the image after dragging to access the content.  Works great with fancybox iframe and enables fast dragging over the iframe. See sample code below.

```
$("#iframePop").fancybox({
             'width': 890,
             'height': 430,
             'type': 'iframe',
             'autoScale': 'false',
             'hideOnContentClick': false,
             'onComplete': function() {
                  $("#fancybox-title").css({'top':'-2px', 'left':'15px', 'bottom':'auto', 'cursor':'move'});                       
                  $("#fancybox-wrap" ).draggable({ handle: "fancybox-title", iframeFix: true, 
                        start: function(ev,ui){$("#fancybox-wrap").append("<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/transparent.png")' id='hidenImg' style='border: 1px solid black; width: 640px; height: 400px; top: 20px; position: absolute; z-index: 10000;' />")}, 
                        drag: function(ev,ui){}, 
                        stop: function(ev, ui){$("#fancybox-wrap #hidenDiv").remove()} 
                  });  
                }
         });
```