# Fancybox Drag window around

Tags: jquery, fancybox, drag

How can I drag a fancybox lightbox window around by clicking the title element?

Comment: yes. yes there is a way.

Comment: Changed the question wording, it was very stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Here's a good resource that should get you started: [draggable fancybox](http://jquery.diaz-cornen.com/fancybox/index_dragfancybox.html)

Comment: That link is obsolete (I wrote it for fancybox v1.2.1)... rather check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/10781937/1055987 with updated demo.