# How to make the Lightbox draggable in Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

I want to make the lighbox draggable for Fancybox. The fancybox is 2.1.5. Please help me.

I tried the easy.drag.js but it won't either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10781937/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Fancybox draggable  issue with Scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725866/jquery-fancybox-draggable-issue-with-scrollbars)

Comment: just make sure that you use the proper API options and selectors for v2.x